# Mysql Trigger that ask for First Day of every month

Tags: mysql

I need to create a trigger that sum the total of the Fuel spent of every month stored on a column named Total (same table) that keep the running total of the Fuel spent BUT when day 1 of every month  I need to start the sum again from the first value  so I can keep to month totals only + running totals of everymonth.  The column in where I save the current values is "LtsUsedTot". I have the following code but it give me errors.

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER `FuelTotalColumn_BEFORE` BEFORE INSERT ON `FuelStationTEST`
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
IF(DAY(CURRENT_DATE()) = 1 THEN  // Not sure if this part is correct
  SET NEW.Total = NEW.LtsUsedTot;
ELSE
  SET NEW.Total = NEW.LtsUsedTot + SUM(LtsUsedTot); //?? here I'm confused
END IF;
END;
$$
DELIMITER;
```

Comment: 'SUM' works on a 'set of rows' so _SUM(LtsUsedTot)_ on the current row is confusing _mysql_. [12.16.1 GROUP BY (Aggregate) Functions](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html) .

Comment: Ok I see, I'll take a look on that, I'm also confused :-) . I'll keep working on it.  Thanks for your comment.